# Case Statements in Ruby (line.scan)

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I'm using named rexeg capture groups and my case statement works with `match`, but it gives me data that I don't want. When I run the code below it only works to match one statement. Where am I going wrong?

```
File::open(file).lines do |line|
    case
      when line.scan(regex1) then puts line.scan(regex1)
      when line.scan(regex2) then puts line.scan(regex2)
      when line.scan(regex3) then puts line.scan(regex3)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case`executes the first true-expresion.

If you have multiple checks, where each check can be true, you should use mutliple `if`-statements.

```
File::open(file).lines do |line|
  puts line.scan(regex1) if line.scan(regex1)
  puts line.scan(regex2) if line.scan(regex2)
  puts line.scan(regex3) if line.scan(regex3)
end
```

I think the following version is a bit more flexible and efficient:

```
File::open(file).lines do |line|
  [ regex1, regex2, regex3] do |regex|
    if result =  line.scan(regex)
            puts result
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the extra example, though I'm actually not going to just print the regexp. I could see that being useful in the future.